# Xtend Template Notation

Tags: code-generation, xtend

i have a Problem with the Xtend Template Notation.

I want to do `«i=i+1»` in a template method

```
def generateSomething() '''
...
«i=i+1»
... 
'''
```

The `«i=i+1»` is  obviously only to count i higher but it also shows the value of i in the generated file too. But i dont want that. Is there a way to solve this problem without changing the method?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a block expression :

```
def generateSomething() '''
...
«{i=i+1 ''}»
... 
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to used [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement%28%29) instead of an int for your code then this should work.

```
val i = new AtomicInteger
val generated = '''
        ...
        «i.andIncrement»
        ... 
        '''
```

Answer (score 0):

`«FOR i : 0..iMaxInclusive»
some text «somelist.get(i)» more text 
«ENDFOR»`